# Make a curve smaller to find the volume of a shell

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, curves

So I've got to calculate the volume of steel necessary to make the carcass of the starship Enterprise. To to so I divided the ship into a few curves and used geogebra to make approximate regressions to find the curves. The first way I did it was calculating the surface of revolution of the many curves and then multiplicating by a certain height (5cm) to find a volume. But I was told by my teacher that I needed to make my work richer, to do so I had to calculate the volume of the carcass by another way. So the idea is to calculate the integral of the original curve and then find one curve that is "smaller" that goes "inside" the original one and calculate it's integral. The next step would be to subtract the integral from the smaller curve from the integral of the original curve.

The problem is that I don't know how to find this "smaller" curve. I want to start with an exponential curve, and for each point on that curve I want to find the orthogonal vector and map that point a distance $a$ along the orthogonal vector. Is there a way for me to take this original curve and find this curve that has all the tangents parallel to the original one always keeping a defined constant distance? 
[image]

Comment: Define "smaller". For that matter, define "square units" here... I presume you are speaking of translations, and since curves have no good concept of "area" (unless they are closed, though you don't seem to speak of this) I'm not sure how you are getting square units. Perhaps a diagram could help here. Could you try to explain yourself better and possibly provide a diagram?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen for example I have a parabolic curve (with the curve pointing downwards) the smaller one would be inside this curve

Comment: Well, umm... I think you are either talking about scaling or translation, or possibly even both. I really need a picture to be sure though. I would first write your quadratic in the form $y = a(x - h)^2 + k$, and then t scale a parabola you just change $a$ and to translate vertically you change $k$ (to translate horizontally you change $h)$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I'm trying to upload it, but I don't have enough reputation yet.... Just got into the forum. I think you understood what I'm trying to do. I used a parabolic curve as an example but what I'm actually dealing with is a exponential curve, do you have any idea how I can do this.

Comment: Just host on imgur or something if necessary, and send me a link. I can upload it to the body of the post. As for an exponential curve? Well... it's the exact same. You still translate vertically by adding a constant $k$. To scale, you multiply by a constant $a$. You just have to remember that your $y$-intercept is not just $k$ now, it is $k+a$. Take the good-old exponential function $e^x$ for example. We can first scale it by $2$ to get $2e^x$, which has a $y$-intercept at $y=2$, and then we can translate vertically by $1$ to get $2e^x+1$, which doesn't cross your curve at all (in a sense...

Comment: ... it is "inside the curve" as you mentioned earlier) with a $y$ intercept of $3$.

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question... if it doesn't I can continue to try to help. If it does, I will post it as an answer and you can accept it.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen http://9gag.com/gag/agqj6YW?ref=android, it's a link to the pic of the diagram, the blue curve is what I'm trying to achieve. I understood what you sad, but is that precise?

Comment: Well, this depends on what you want. The simplest way to do it is the way I said.... If your goal is to have it be "pipe like"  (in that the nearest distance from one curve to the other is a constant, say one I.e. The pipe is of constant thickness) then you have a problem in that the calculations get much tougher. Is this what you want?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen sadly yes, I'm trying to calculate volume necessary to make the carcass of the starship Enterprise(I divided it into many curves), I've already done it using the surface of a revolution formula, but my teacher said that to make my work richer I should do it by having the integral of the outside curve subtracted by an integral of a "smaller" version of the curve too

Comment: well, OK. I understand you now. The problem here is that exponential curves don't play well under those conditions. It can be done in theory (though I've never done it). Let's take $e^x$ as our example. First of all, the orthogonal line to a point $(x_0, e^{x_0}) $ is going to be $y= e^{x_0} - e^{-x_0} (x-x_0) $ by point slope. We need a function that moves each point on the curve $e^x$ one unit along the orthogonal line at that point. I'll hammer away at the problem and let you know if I can get anything.

Comment: I have a bit of work I need to get done today first, but I have an idea for how to solve your problem. I'll get back to you within 6 hours if all goes well.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen no Problem. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: no problem. Btw, in the mean time you might want to edit your post to include the things we discussed in the comments... Mention that you desire to take an exponential function and  find a curve where the nearest distance from that curve to the exponential curve (i.e. The distance along the orthogonal line to the exponential curve) is a constant. This will make your question less likely to be closed, and make other people more likely to understand and answer your post.

Comment: Hmm. When you edited your post you didn't include nearly enough detail, you got the opposite of what you intended... The question was closed down. Your post definitely needed at least a few paragraphs in detail explaining what you meant, along with anything you've tried so far. Oh well... I can continue to help in comments. I would severely edit your question though, and put it in queue for reopening. I can do the edits myself later if you want :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen oh sorry, actually I'm still editing, as I'm on my phone I was going to do it in parts because I couldn't read everything you said and transcript to there at the same time. How do I put in the queue to reopening? I will try putting the most detail as possible. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I edited it again, if you don't think is enough you can say that that I edit it till it's enough. Thanks once again

Comment: I think the background you gave us fantastic! Only thing I might add is a little more clarification as to what your last sentence means... The tangents at what points? I would clarify (in more detail than I give here) that if you take a given point on the  exponential curve,  you first find the orthogonal line at that point and then let your other point be where that orthogonal line crosses your new curve. You make sure the tangents match at both points (and make sure this process works for all points on the exponential curve)

Comment: Even more simply, I would say that you want to start with an exponential curve, and for each point on that curve you want to find the orthogonal vector and map that point a distance $a$ along the orthogonal vector. Do this for all points. A clean and detailed diagram showing this would help tremendously too. Your first image was good, but was a little hard to understand and wasn't labeled/cleaned up at all. Also, separate your paragraph about finding the curve, and maybe format it so it's clear what you are asking! After that I would say your post is definitely as good as it's going to get.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen is it okay now?

Comment: Looks good to me. I nominated it for reopening now, and added your picture to the body of the post. Now that I am home I'll try to work on this problem a bit more

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen thanks a lot for the help, I'll answer as fast as possible

Comment: Ok, good news and bad news. Good news is that your question is reopened. Bad news is that the only answer I can get is parametric... I should finish writing up the body of my post soon, but in short here it is: Let's start with the easy curve $e^x$. What is the companion curve $1$ unit away along the orthogonal line at all points? $\left(t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2t}}},e^t+\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2t}}}\right)$ for $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Mathematica won't return a closed form in Cartesian Coordinates no matter how much I've tried. You might need to do calculus on Parametric Equations (turning $e^x$ into a parametric equation as well) to get the answer you seek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We begin with $(x_1,y_1)$ on your exponential curve. For now, let's assume we are working with $e^x$ (the generalization should be clear, but I leave the work to the OP unless more help is needed.) Thus, we can write any point on our first curve as $(x_1,e^{x_1})$ where $y_2=e^{x_1}$. I will also assume that the constant distance along orthogonal line is $1$.

We clearly have that the orthogonal line is $y=e^{x_1}-e^{-x_1}(x-x_1)$. The most important thing here is the slope of $-e^{-x_1}$. What this slope means is that the difference in the $y$ coordinates of our point $(x_1, y_1)$ on the exponential curve and our point $(x_2, y_2)$, which we will call $\Delta y$, is equal to the change in the $x$-coordinates ($\Delta x$) scaled by $e^{-x_1}$. Symbolically, this means that
$$\Delta y = e^{-x_1} \Delta x$$
If we draw a triangle with hypotenuse $1$ (the length along orthogonal line), and legs $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ and substitute the above equality and the Pythagorean Theorem, we find that
$$(\Delta x)^2e^{-2x_1}+(\Delta x)^2 = 1 \implies \Delta x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2x_1}}} \implies \Delta y=\frac{e^{-x_1}}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2x_1}}}$$
All that is left is to note the direction we want to transform $(x_1,y_1)$. The new curve will be above and to the left, meaning that we want to decrease $x_1$ by $\Delta x$ and we want to increase $y_1$ by $\Delta y$. Writing this out, we find that
$$x_2 = x_1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2x_1}}}$$
$$y_2 = y_1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2x_1}}} = e^{x_1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2x_1}}}$$
Note that, if we run along all of the values $x_1$ could take on, we draw out our new curve. Thus, we can replace $x_1$ with $t$ and get a parametric curve
$$\left(t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2t}}},e^t+\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2t}}}\right)$$
We must let $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$ for this to draw out all of the needed points. Here is a picture from a Desmos graph I made. It shows the orthogonal line as well as the points where the line intersects both curves (the purple curve is the parametric function)
  [image]
[Here is a link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x63dhzyplo) to the Desmos graph I made where you can play around with this curve *(which I would duplicate to your own Desmos profile if you want to keep it, as it may at some point be deleted by either myself or Desmos, though I tend to note delete my more important graphs)*

Unfortunately, this still doesn't solve your integration problem. In order to integrate you are going to use calculus on these parametric equations. In order to do this, I will quote [this Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution#Parametric_form):

> When a curve is defined by its parametric form $(x(t),y(t))$ in some
>   interval $[a,b]$, the volumes of the solids generated by revolving the
>   curve around the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis are given by
>   $$V_x = \int_a^b \pi y^2 \frac{dx}{dt} dt$$
>   $$V_y = \int_a^b \pi x^2 \frac{dy}{dt} dt$$

Subtract this from the volume you get revolving the outside curve along the interval you want, and you are golden. If you are afraid you made an error, just scale an exponential curve to be roughly the same shape as the parametric one you need and do the integration. If your answers are close, then you can sleep soundly!

All that is left is for you to generalize the methods I used. Instead of $y_1 = e^{x_1}$ you will have that $y_1 = f(x_1)$, and instead of setting the hypotenuse of the triangle to be $1$ you will set it to be $c$ (where $c$ is your constant). The only trouble I can see is in scaling extra constants in $f(x_1)$, which we didn't have here. Let me know if you have trouble generalizing.

Comment: @MarcoKoblinsky No problem at all! If you like the answer feel free to upvote, and if it answers your question please accept. If you need any further help don't hesitate to let me know!

Comment: So for me to apply this to the function 0.05e^{0.73x} I should change all e^{x} and e^{x1} to 0.05e^{0.73x}? And where exactly is this 1 I have to change? I tried doing it this way and also changing only the y1, I couldn't made it work. Thanks again

Comment: @MarcoKoblinsky don't just replace them in the formula... You'll have to recalculate everything (I would do it in the most general form that encompasses all your formulas if you need to do this for more than one curve). In your case you need to let $y_1 = 0.05e^{0.73x_1}$. The constant $1$ is the the hypteneuse of the triangle that must be drawn, with legs $\Delta x$ and \Delta y$. You will need to change the constant (and thus the length of the hypotenuse) to whatever it is in your model of the Enterprise. Start from the first step and go through every step again with your new function to...

Comment: ...  ensure that everything works out nicely.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will try doing it that way. Sorry for anything

Comment: @MarcoKoblinsky no need to apologize... Helping with math is what love to do :) heck, if you can't figure out your example I can even edit my post to include it later (though that would take a while, so it wouldn't be today for sure)

Comment: thank you so much. You have no idea how you helped me. I think I understood what you did and I'm applying it to the functions I found using the regressions but I'm still not done, I'll finish it tomorrow (it's 3 in the morning here in Brazil). If I have any problems I'll let you know. Just one more question, is it possible to "unparametrize" this function? And Merry Christmas! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @MarcoKoblinsky unfortunately, I don't think that's it's possible to convert these equations to Parametric form. Mathematica returned a different form that has no fractions (but has powers of $x$ and $y$) but couldn't find a way to eliminate the variable $t$. Given the simplicity of the functions, I'm guessing that means there's no closed form available. I'll let you know if I find anything, but I'm pretty sure the parametric function is not technically an exponential curve anymore, so all that I could get you would be a power series. What level of calculus are you at?

Comment: @MarcoKoblinsky oh, and a Merry Christmas to you to!